grid in circle shape
i want to instance an object in a grid in a circle shape like this.

The instancing works and I also can create a grid but I don't know how to make it a circle shape.
This is my setup with the Less Than Nodes. But I don't know what to set up.



Test if Position > Length (vector) > Less Than. You can delete either points or instances based on that.

What kind of node do you mean? And where do I have to put it? After instance on points, right? @Lutzi

I gave you the exact names with emphasis. Try deleting on your points you feed into the Instance on Points, it'd make the most sense to me.

I don't know what's a node of those words. There's no Length Node, no Less Than Node. I only find position node. I simply never saw those and don't which node you mean. @Lutzi

For the Length, you may have a look here : Vector Math Node. For the Less Than, you may have a look here : Compare Node. You can also directly plug the Less Than node into the Selection socket of the Instance on Points node, not having to delete things afterwards.

Thank you very much. That helped! But now I struggle on what to set where.

Another way to the get a point grid in a circular shape would be to use a thin cylinder, make it a volume and then use Distribute Points in Volume set to Grid for getting points within a circle to instance objects on, like this: point grid

Awesome, thank you! @GordonBrinkmann

@GordonBrinkmann Do you know how I then could mirror every 2nd column of the grid? So in every 2nd column the objects are mirrored?

(Using Blender 3.6.12)
Following is a graph combining Lutzi's proposal with dark green nodes and a way to mirror every 2nd column with dark pink nodes:

Resources: 

Side note: It is to notice in the Spreadsheet Editor that the scaling by -1 along X direction is recorded as a rotation by 180° around Z axis...

More precisely : Blender appears to need all 3 coordinates of scaling to be the same sign. Flipping X axis flips Y and Z as well. So it adds a 180° rotation along Z axis to compensate. I've never noticed that behavior but a quick testing on your file brings me to believe that's how it works.

Wow that's a very easy node tree. Thank you very much! I'll try to understand it!

@StefLAncien What is the group input? I feel like it's not just the imported node, right? Because where do I get the resolution output from?

@adrian.blender The Group Input node is by default providing the Geometry the GN modifier is attached to. If an input socket of another node is connected to the empty socket that is always present as the last socket of the Group Input node, this socket becomes an Input for the GN graph. Its properties can be edited using the side panel of the GN Editor. At the same time, a new entry is created in the Modifier Properties panel (at the right side of the default GUI). Using Ctrl+h, unused sockets are hidden. This is why only Radius and Resolution are displayed, not the last empty.
